# Jtable single cell having multiple images

Tags: java, image, swing, jtable

I want to display multiple images in a single cell of a jtable.I know how to display a single image in a cell but how to do the same in case of multiple images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to display multiple images in a single cell of a jtable.I know
>   how to display a single image in a cell but how to do the same in case
>   of multiple images?

- I'm wouldn't going this way, because XxxRanderer is called from every mouse and Key events over visible JTables Rectangle in the JViewport,
- prepare this image before, put together all images to one and put only one Icon/ImageIcon to XxxTableModel

  ---
- DefaultCellRenderer returns JLabel by default, add proper LayoutManager to JLabel and laid there images, save images to local variable to avoiding any FileIO on runtime

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two ways I can think of doing this...

You could merge all the images into a single image and allow the default `TableCellRenderer` to render the result as normal

Or...

You need to supply your own `TableCellRenderer` capable of taking the multiple images and displaying them.

Probably the simplest would be to use a `JPanel` as a base and add a `JLabel` per image.  This would be a rather expensive process (assuming your have a dynamic number of images per cell), as you would need to remove all the labels from the panel and add the new ones for EACH cell.

See [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) for more details.